# AWS broken pipe error when uploading files bigger than 1 MB

Tags: django, amazon-s3, broken-pipe

I am a django newbie, and I inherited a django back-end with little documentation. I am making a request to said server, which is hosted on AWS. To store the files in the request we use S3.
I have found nothing on the django code that limits the size of the file uploads, and I suspect it may be AWS closing the connection because of file size.

This is the code I use, and below the error I get whenever the total size of the files is over 1 MB:

```
import requests
json_dict = {'key_1':'value_1','video':video,'image':,image}
requests.post('https://api.test.whatever.io/v1/register', json=dict_reg)
```

video is a video file ('.mov','.avi','.mp4',etc) with base64 encoding, and image is an image file ('.jpg','.png') with base64 encoding.

And this is the trace I get, ONLY when the total size is over 1 MB:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:132: InsecurePlatfo
rmWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 
from configuring SSL
appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade 
to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see 
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
InsecurePlatformWarningTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in 
post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in 
request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 
488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 
609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 
473, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 
'Broken pipe'))
```

**As mentioned previously, I have not found anywhere in the django code a limit to the file size, any hints where I should be looking at?**
I also did not find anything on the AWS S3 policy.

Comment: When you say MG do you mean MB? And are you on dev server or a production web server?

Comment: yep, sorry, MB. It happens on both (production and dev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Nginx to reverse proxy your HTTP requests? if yes check this [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-upload-a-very-large-file-use-django-on-nginx#).

Also see the value set for the below value in settings for the Upload Handlers in django

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
```

Comment: thanks. there is a varilable FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE but it is called nowhere in the code. I will check your link. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. It will not be called in the code directly but is used by Django to manage uploads. Setting  a higher value will not prevent timeouts when used alongwith bypassing Nginx proxying.

Comment: good point. actually the problem was with the nginx.conf file, see below.

Comment: You are the welcome, though I hope you realise you have now just kicked the can down the road (til you need a 2mb file upload). You can bypass nginx altogether for file uploads, which will prevent buffering at nginx end. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted to help others with the same issue (alongwith a small bump for me :D ).

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was the `nginx` configuration. changing the variable `client_max_body_size` in the `nginx.conf`file from `1M` to `2M` did the trick.